# Vue Router перенаправляет в корень | Как сделать относительный путь vue-router

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

У меня есть чистый проект vue-cli в котором есть vue 3 и vue-router. Проблема в том что после билда я запускаю из пути `localhost/test/dist/` и видно на странице только меню, при нажатии на пункт меню страница отображается, но url меняется на `localhost/about`.

В `vue.config.js` указано значение `publicPath: ""`.

Что нужно прописать в конфиге или где-то ещё что бы путь vue-router был относительным?

Comment: прикрепите ваш код

Comment: @AleksandrBelous я уже решил проблему. Код полностью стандартный после создания нового проекта vue-cli. Так же код какого файла нужно приложить? (хоть я уже и решил проблему, но если нужно то я добавлю, что бы было более ясно остальным кто столкнётся с такой же проблемой)

Answer (score 1):

Я решил проблему так:

```
const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(window.location.pathname), // здесь заменив process.env.BASE_URL на window.location.pathname
  routes
})
```

И теперь пути идут правильно.

Проблемы бала больше связана с тем что я искал в интернете и в документации, а вся она была для старой версии vue-router. Найдя новую и поняв что я смотрел не то я сделал как написал выше. (до пытался сделать указывая `base: ...`)